# How do you know to use Container.DataItem when data binding in ASP.NET? Is there a reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, eval, bind

Is there a reference for data binding?  I've seen a bunch of different ways to data bind things, but I've never found a reference.  Is there one?

I know there are Bind and Eval, but when does Container.DataItem come into play?  Are there other "hidden" objects and methods available?  Or is Container.DataItem the object that is being used here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> when does Container.DataItem come into
>   play?

From the first link below (paraphrasing slightly): "Container.DataItem is a runtime alias for the DataItem for this specific item in a bound list."

> Are there other "hidden" objects and
>   methods available?

Definitely the other [`DataBinder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.aspx) class members, plus [`TemplateControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.aspx), which houses `Eval` and provides methods to query bound Xml data.

> I've seen a bunch of different ways to
>   data bind things, but I've never found
>   a reference. Is there one?

These are as close as you'll get:

- [What's the deal with Databinder.Eval and Container.DataItem?](http://blog4asp.blogspot.com/2012/06/whats-deal-with-databindereval-and.html) (Short and sweet)
- [ASP.NET data binding overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860)
- [Data-Binding Expressions Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: Note, the first and third links are no longer valid

Comment: @GaryRichter - links fixed

Comment: 2nd-link no longer valid (ASP.NET data binding overview)