# INT converted to boolean updateable in a checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, checkbox

I have been programming for many years, about 10 in an older version of .NET, as a result I'm new to LINQ, UpdatePanels and Ajax and their way of doing things.
The following code works correctly.
The database field is defined as:

```
rptPriority INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
```

A much simplified page stub which works is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upReport" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="dvReport" runat="server" DataSourceID="ldsReport" CssClass="reset"
            AutoGenerateRows="False" DefaultMode="Edit" Width="100%">
            <Fields>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DynamicControl ID="Priority" runat="server" DataField="rptPriority" Mode="Edit" CssClass="general" />
```

etc
What I need to do is change that Dynamic Control as a textbox to a checkbox which is updatable and driven by the same data. The following gives the correct data but doesn't update.
Were I doing this using straight SQL or PROCEDURES, this would not be a big problem. (also not an option)

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Priority" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("rptPriority")) %>' />
```

I changed "Eval" to "Bind" and got the "ERROR CS0103: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context"
I suspect that the "Convert.ToBoolean" is part of the problem.
There are many pages which I've perused trying to get the info I need. Among them [How to add checkbox to datagrid in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319629/how-to-add-checkbox-to-datagrid-in-vb-net) , [Html.CheckBox returns false if disabled, even if seleced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718356/html-checkbox-returns-false-if-disabled-even-if-seleced) and [Checkbox server/client events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238639/checkbox-server-client-events) , [How do you know to use Container.DataItem when data binding in ASP.NET? Is there a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876719/how-do-you-know-to-use-container-dataitem-when-data-binding-in-asp-net-is-there) , [The databind bind() function belongs to which class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866066/the-databind-bind-function-belongs-to-which-class) not to mention about 50 more outside of stack overflow which got me to where I am now.
**Edit**
As per Rob's suggestion, I added the following, but couldn't get / find any way to use "DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs".

```
protected void dvReport_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView dv = sender as DetailsView;
    CheckBox ctlPriority = dv.FindControl("Priority") as CheckBox;
    e.NewValues["rptPriority"] = ctlPriority.Checked ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The following is a stub from the save / update code behind.

```
protected void btnSave_OnCLick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RadioButtonList rblReportStatus = (RadioButtonList)dvReport.FindControl("rblReportStatus");

  using (RiderReportDataContext db = new RiderReportDataContext())
  {
    Report report = null;
    Contact contact = null;
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    bool doUpdate = false;

    ldsContact.Updating += (o, ea) =>
    {
      Contact original = (Contact)ea.OriginalObject;
      contact = (Contact)ea.NewObject;

      if (
        original.FirstName != contact.FirstName ||
...
        original.Email != contact.Email)
      {
        doUpdate = true;
      }

      db.Contacts.Attach(contact, original);

      ea.Cancel = true;
    };

    // force the update procedure
    dvContact.UpdateItem(true);

    ldsReport.Updating += (o, ea) =>
    {
      Report original = ea.OriginalObject as Report;
      report = ea.NewObject as Report;

      if (rblReportStatus.SelectedItem != null)
      {
        report.ReportStatusId = int.Parse(rblReportStatus.SelectedValue);
      }

      if (
        original.ReportStatusId != report.ReportStatusId ||
        original.SourceId != report.SourceId ||
...
        original.ReportTypeID != report.ReportTypeID ||
        original.rptPriority != report.rptPriority ||       // The value here doesn't change
        original.SupervisorId != report.SupervisorId)
      {
        doUpdate = true;
      }
      db.Reports.Attach(report, original);
      ea.Cancel = true;
    };

    // force the update procedure
    dvReport.UpdateItem(true);

// Other Search For Updates

    if (doUpdate)
    {
      contact.ChangedOn = now;
      report.ChangedOn = now;

      Log log = new Log();
      log.ReportId = report.Id;
      log.UserId = MembershipClass.User.Id;
      log.Text = "The report updated.";
      log.CreatedOn = now;
      report.Logs.Add(log);

      db.SubmitChanges();
    }
  }

  if (Page.IsValid)
  {
    Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx" /*table.ListActionPath */);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your updatepanel UpdateMode is conditional. Have you called updatepanel1.update() method on server side...?? Either make UpdateMode="Always".

Comment: UpdateMode="Conditional" is mandatory since there are 4 update panels in the page.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, `Bind()` doesn't provide an easy way to convert a data type.  You will find other answers which suggest changing the type of the data you are binding to, but I understand this isn't an option in your case.

I think your best solution is to go back to one-way binding.  e.g. use your existing code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Priority" runat="server"
   Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("rptPriority")) %>' />
```

Which will correctly set the value of the checkbox when the `DetailsView` is rendered, but will not provide a value for rptPriority when the details are updated.  For this you'll need to add an `OnItemUpdating` event handler to your `DetailsView`, which will allow you to perform the custom conversion your need.  e.g.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvReport" runat="server"
   onitemupdating="dvReport_ItemUpdating"
```

And the implementation in your code-behind will look like this:-

```
protected void dvReport_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView dv = sender as DetailsView;
    CheckBox ctlPriority = dv.FindControl("Priority") as CheckBox;
    e.NewValues["rptPriority"] = ctlPriority.Checked ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This appears to be the correct way of doing this. I put it in and I missed something. The event is not firing.

Comment: The event should fire if you are updating (you'll need to provide a handler for ItemInserting if inserting new data.  What is the name of the command on your command button?

Comment: this is an update. The insert is handled by default.

Comment: OK, great.  To get to the bottom of why your event handler is not being called, can you show us the code for your command button (e.g. how is the update being invoked).